# How to find forks of a deleted Github project?

Tags: github, fork, blockchain

[Someone's commit on this repo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ekdl.png)I am looking for a repo: https://github.com/cdgex-group.
It was available just a couple of days ago but got deleted recently. How can I find forks of it?

Comment: If you know the individuals who created it they likely have private forks still available in their source code. If you don't know them you can parse the JSON file located at https://www.gharchive.org/ and contact their e-mail or information they have listed.

Comment: The repo was public. So all those forks made before should still be public, right?

Comment: All the forks should be public but it depends on who made the forks for the project. I couldn't find any public information on the project "cdgex-group" online so are you sure you got the name correct?

Comment: Yes, it is this name. I swear I accessed on Wednesday.... I have attached an image of someone made a commit on this repo.

Comment: I saw that too, why do you want the repo though? What was it based on and what did it do? You can likely find a similar one online.

Comment: It is a trading engine for exchanges. I saw the notice "cdgex exchange is failing so we open sourced our code" on that page before. The code quality is better than almost all other open source projects right now. It is based on Java. It would be really sad if they just took it offline permanently.